# Why my redis error is showing socketfailure error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, redis

I have a project containing MVC and API. So right now my database is getting used every time when I reload page. So I am implementing Redis in both MVC and API. What I am doing is if the key is already present in redis than MVC will check it and fetch the data from there, and if not than it will send the request to API that will fetch the data from database and set it in Redis with a default time of 30 minutes.

This is my Redis Class library:

```
public class Redis{
static StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\connectionLog.txt")
static ConnectionMultiplexer redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("connectionstring",writer);
static readonly IDatabaseAsync dbConnection = redisConnection.GetDatabase();

        public static async Task SetRecordAsync<T>(string recordId, T data, TimeSpan? timeSpan = null)//default 30 mins
        {
            var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data);

            if (timeSpan.HasValue)
            {
                await dbConnection.StringSetAsync(recordId, jsonData, timeSpan);
            }
            else
            {
                timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
                await dbConnection.StringSetAsync(recordId, jsonData, timeSpan);
            }
        }

        public static async Task<T> GetValueAsync<T>(string recordId)
        {
            var data = await dbConnection.StringGetAsync(recordId);
            var jsonData = data.ToString();

            if (jsonData is null)
            {
                return default(T);
            }

            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(jsonData);
        }

        public static async Task DeleteValueAsync(string recordId)
        {
            await dbConnection.KeyDeleteAsync(recordId);
        }

        public static async Task<bool> IsKeyNull(string recordId)
        {
            var value = await dbConnection.StringGetAsync(recordId);
            var isNull = value.IsNullOrEmpty ? true : false;
            return isNull;
        }
}
```

Whats confusing me is the fact that when I using the method `IsKeyNull`(This method returns true because initially no key is present and hence no value) from the redis classs library then code is working fine:

```
//Code in API
if (await Redis.IsKeyNull(Constant.RedisConstants.XYZ))
                {
                    var url = string.Format(ApiUrl.GetOnlineXYZCount, storeId);
                    result = await HttpClientHelper.GetHttpResponseMessage(url);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
                    result.Data = Redis.GetValueAsync<int>(Constant.RedisConstants.XYZ).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
```

But when it gets true in above condition then API is called and this code is being run:

```
//API
if(Redis.IsKeyNull(Constants.RedisConstants.XYZ).GetAwaiter().GetResult()) 
            {
                using (var uow = UnitOfWork)
                {
                    var result = uow.Repository<Data.EntityFramework.Order>().Count(database query);
                    Task task = Redis.SetRecordAsync<int>(Constants.RedisConstants.Order, result);
                    task.Wait();
                    response.Result = result;
                }
            }
```

Now the above code creates the problem, when the code hit `Redis.IsKeyNull(Constants.RedisConstants.XYZ).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, an error is thrown:

```
StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=No connection is active/available to service this operation: GET Order; A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: ASR-PC, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=8190,Min=4,Max=8191), v: 2.1x.58.3xyz
  Source=StackExchange.Redis
  StackTrace:
   at StackExchange.Redis.ConnectionMultiplexer.ThrowFailed[T](TaskCompletionSource`1 source, Exception unthrownException) in /_/src/StackExchange.Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs:line 2777
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at RedisCache.DistributedCacheExtensions.<IsKeyNull>d__4.MoveNext() in RedisCache\DistributedCacheExtensions.cs:line 67
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at BusinessLogic.Services.Order.OrderService.GetOnlineOrderCount(Int32 storeId) in OrderService.cs:line 1846
   at GetOnlineOrderCount(Int32 storeId) in Api\Controllers\Order\OrderController.cs:line 443
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object instance, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Inner Exception 1:
RedisConnectionException: SocketFailure on windows.net:6380/Subscription, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 10s ago, last-write: 10s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 10s ago, v: 2.x.58.3xyz

Inner Exception 2:
IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall.

Inner Exception 3:
SocketException: A blocking operation was interrupted by a call to WSACancelBlockingCall
```

The log I received from my redis connectivity is this(connectionLog.txt):

```
redis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380,syncTimeout=100000000,connectTimeout=100000000,password=*****,ssl=True,connectRetry=8

Connecting redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive...
BeginConnect: redis.cache.windows.net:6380
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 1.03:46:40 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=1,Free=8190,Min=4,Max=8191)
Configuring TLS
connection failed: redis.cache.windows.net:6380 (Subscription, SocketFailure): SocketFailure on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Subscription, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 30s ago, last-write: 30s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
connection failed: redis.cache.windows.net:6380 (Interactive, SocketFailure): SocketFailure on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 30s ago, last-write: 30s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
> Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
> An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
Finished awaiting tasks, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
redis.cache.windows.net:6380 faulted: SocketFailure on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 30s ago, last-write: 30s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
Waiting for tiebreakers...
All tasks are already complete
redis.cache.windows.net:6380 failed to nominate (Faulted)
> SocketFailure on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: ConnectedAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 30s ago, last-write: 30s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
No masters detected
redis.cache.windows.net:6380: Standalone v3.0.0, master; keep-alive: 00:01:00; int: Connecting; sub: Connecting; not in use: DidNotRespond
redis.cache.windows.net:6380: int ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2; sub ops=0, qu=0, qs=0, qc=0, wr=0, socks=2
Circular op-count snapshot; int: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s); sub: 0 (0.00 ops/s; spans 10s)
Sync timeouts: 0; async timeouts: 0; fire and forget: 0; last heartbeat: -1s ago
resetting failing connections to retry...
retrying; attempts left: 7...
1 unique nodes specified
Requesting tie-break from redis.cache.windows.net:6380 > __Booksleeve_TieBreak...
Allowing endpoints 1.03:46:40 to respond...
Awaiting task completion, IOCP: (Busy=2,Free=998,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
Finished awaiting tasks, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=8189,Min=4,Max=8191)
redis.cache.windows.net:6380 faulted: UnableToConnect on redis.cache.windows.net:6380/Interactive, Initializing/NotStarted, last: NONE, origin: BeginConnectAsync, outstanding: 0, last-read: 0s ago, last-write: 0s ago, keep-alive: 60s, state: Connecting, mgr: 10 of 10 available, last-heartbeat: never, global: 30s ago, v: 2.1.58.34321
Waiting for tiebreakers...
All tasks are already complete
redis-red
```

This is what my connection string looks like:

```
windows.net:6380,password=xyz=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,connectTimeout=10000,connectRetry=8,syncTimeout=3000
```

Comment: When I am using the same class library ```Redis``` in my console application, with keys:```string``` type and values:```string``` and ```int``` type then it works totally fine. I am not sure but I guess maybe the issue is using same ports by both MVC and API or maybe I am missing something in redis server connection string.

Comment: This is what my simple program looks like:   ``` Task task = Redis.SetRecordAsync<string>("Anir", "Rawa");
                task.Wait();
                var lp = Redis.GetValueAsync<string>("Anir").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                Console.WriteLine(lp);```